# Tesseract API - get each text box with position

Tags: c++, ocr, tesseract

I need to write a program which can get each text box from an image

I need the text and the position from each text box in same way as `tesseract hocr` does

Could anyone give me some hints or even better a link to an example explaining how to do it :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20831612/getting-the-bounding-box-of-the-recognized-words-using-python-tesseract

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ResultIterator` API was designed to provide such data. Check out Tesseract [APIExample](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/APIExample) codes.